# Harddisk is almost full but i don't have anything

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, virus

My free harddisk space is almost full but when i select all folder inside the C:/ drive(including unvisible folders) it shows only 70 GB. What is the problem ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hDvF.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1hDvF.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try downloading windirstat which is a utility to give in depth information about the folders and sizes. https://windirstat.net

Comment: This is really more of a comment rather than an answer. Yes, WinDirStat is a helpful (if old, and there are better options) tool for this problem, more information about HOW one should use WinDirStat to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes I know but I don't have enough reputation to comment

Comment: You have sufficient points to submit an answer, which means you need to submit an answer's-worth of information. If you know how to use WinDirStat to fix this problem then you should do so now. If you cannot explain to OP how to use WinDirStat to resolve this, then you should avoid posting an answer. The way to get more points is to do a good job with what you can do. Each of us were in this position at one point.

Answer (score 1):

I can see only one folder in your images. You are not selecting the whole disk.

You should look at the disk in Windows Explorer by right-click of `C:`
and selecting Properties. This will give you the right numbers.